# How do I configure group access using OCI IAM and Kubernetes RBAC

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Based on this documentation - https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Concepts/contengaboutaccesscontrol.htm I am trying to configure access to Kubernetes for an Oracle Cloud IAM group, but I can only successfully grant access for individual users.

Steps to reproduce (assumes compartment, cluster, OCI CLI and kubectl configured):

- Create an IAM group - `testgroup`
- Create an IAM user - `testuser`
- Put the user `testuser` into the group `testgroup`
- Create a Policy in your compartment - `kubernetes_dev_access`
- Policy statement - `Allow group testgroup to use clusters in compartment mycompartment`
- Apply the following Kubernetes manifest :

```
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: kubernetes_dev_access
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods", "services"]
  verbs: ["create", "get", "update", "list", "delete", "watch"]
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["create", "get", "update", "list", "delete", "watch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: kubernetes_dev_access_group
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: ocid1.group.oc1..aaaaaaaaabababababababababababababababababa
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: kubernetes_dev_access
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

This should allow my user successfully list the pods :

```
kubectl get pods
```

But I get the following error :

```
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "ocid1.group.oc1..aaaaaaaaabababababababababababababababababa" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "mynamespace"
```

The crucial lines seem to be :

```
- kind: Group
  name: ocid1.group.oc1..aaaaaaaaabababababababababababababababababa
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

If I replace these lines with the following reference to the specific user it works, ie I get the list of pods :

```
- kind: User
  name: ocid1.user.oc1..aaaaaaaaaxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyx
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Any pointers gratefully appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you created a policy to allow users in group to access the Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: @crou - Yes, see post. (`Allow group testgroup to use clusters in compartment mycompartment`)

Answer (score 3):

OKE supports groups in RBAC for at least several months now. So your code should work now.

Comment: For reference, here's their release notes from when the support was added: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/releasenotes/changes/a5597338-55ef-4866-b0ff-b947625afb2b/

Answer (score 0):

OKE doesn't support groups yet in RBAC. You have to define individual users in RBAC policies.

Comment: Please add a reference for this info.

Comment: Agree with ThisIsNoZaku, something official would be useful.

Comment: The docs elude to this fact only uses are supported since it never mentions groups in rbac but you are correct it's not clear. I'll get that fixed. Sorry I forgot to mention I'm on the oke team as disclaimer originally.